# Debug assertion failed - C++ (OpenCV) - pops up after the program terminates

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV version 2.4.9 and Visual Studio 2015. I am sure all the dependencies between them are working, since other sample programs worked perfectly, using OpenCV libraries.

You can find here my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
String face_cascade_name = "C:\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eye_cascade_name = "C:\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml";
Mat faceDetect(Mat img);
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

enum EmotionState_t {
   SERIOUS = 0, // 0
   SMILE, // 1
   SURPRISED, // 2
};

static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images,
  vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {
  std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
  if (!file) {
      string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
          CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
  }
  string line, path, classlabel;
  while (getline(file, line)) {
      stringstream liness(line);
      getline(liness, path, separator);
      getline(liness, classlabel);
      if (!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
          images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
          labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
      }
  }
}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    EmotionState_t emotion;

    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)) {
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
            if (!eyes_cascade.load(eye_cascade_name)) {
                printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

                    // 0 is the ID of the built-in laptop camera, change if you want to useother camera
                    VideoCapture cap(0);

                //check if the file was opened properly
                if (!cap.isOpened())
                {
                    std::cout << "Capture could not be opened succesfully" << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "camera is ok.. Stay 2 ft away from your camera\n" << endl;
                }

                int w = 432;
                int h = 240;
                cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w);
                cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, h);

                Mat frame;
                cap >> frame;

                std::cout << "processing the image...." << endl;

                Mat testSample = faceDetect(frame);
                // Get the path to your CSV.
                string fn_csv = "C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\test_canny\\my_csv.txt";
                // These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels.
                vector<Mat>* images;
                images = new vector<Mat>;
                vector<int>* labels;
                labels = new vector<int>;
                // Read in the data. This can fail if no valid
                // input filename is given.
                try
                {
                    read_csv(fn_csv, *images, *labels);
                }
                catch (cv::Exception& e) {
                    cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: "
                        << e.msg << endl;
                    // nothing more we can do
                    exit(1);
                }
                // Quit if there are not enough images for this demo.
                if ((*images).size() <= 1)
                {
                    string error_message = "This demo needs at least 2 images to work.Please add more images to your data set!";
                        CV_Error(CV_StsError, error_message);
                }
                // Get the height from the first image. We'll need this
                // later in code to reshape the images to their original
                // size:
                int height = (*images)[0].rows;

                // The following lines create an Fisherfaces model for
                // face recognition and train it with the images and
                // labels read from the given CSV file.
                // If you just want to keep 10 Fisherfaces, then call
                // the factory method like this:
                //
                // cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(10);
                //
                // However it is not useful to discard Fisherfaces! Please
                // always try to use _all_ available Fisherfaces for
                // classification.
                //
                // If you want to create a FaceRecognizer with a
                // confidence threshold (e.g. 123.0) and use _all_
                // Fisherfaces, then call it with:
                //
                // cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(0, 123.0);
                //
                Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
                model->train(*images, *labels);

                // The following line predicts the label of a given
                // test image:
                int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);

                // To get the confidence of a prediction call the model with:
                //
                // int predictedLabel = -1;
                // double confidence = 0.0;
                // model->predict(testSample, predictedLabel, confidence);
                //
                string result_message = format("Predicted class = %d", predictedLabel);
                std::cout << result_message << endl;

                // giving the result
                switch (predictedLabel)
                {
                case SMILE:
                    std::cout << "You are happy!" << endl;
                    break;
                case SURPRISED:
                    std::cout << "You are surprised!" << endl;
                    break;
                case SERIOUS:
                    std::cout << "You are serious!" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                return 0;
}

Mat faceDetect(Mat img)
    {
        std::vector<Rect>* faces;
        faces = new vector<Rect>;
        std::vector<Rect>* eyes;
        eyes = new vector<Rect>;
        bool two_eyes = false;
        bool any_eye_detected = false;
        //detecting faces
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, *faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,
            Size(30, 30));
        if ((*faces).size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Try again.. I did not dectected any faces..." << endl;
            exit(-1); // abort everything
        }
        Point p1 = Point(0, 0);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < (*faces).size(); i++)
        {
            // we cannot draw in the image !!! otherwise will mess with the prediction
            // rectangle( img, faces[i], Scalar( 255, 100, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );

            Mat frame_gray;
            cvtColor(img, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            // croping only the face in region defined by faces[i]
            std::vector<Rect>* eyes;
            eyes = new vector<Rect>;
            Mat faceROI = frame_gray((*faces)[i]);
            //In each face, detect eyes
            eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, *eyes, 1.1, 3, 0
                | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

            for (size_t j = 0; j < (*eyes).size(); j++)
            {
                Point center((*faces)[i].x + (*eyes)[j].x + (*eyes)[j].width*0.5,
                    (*faces)[i].y + (*eyes)[j].y + (*eyes)[j].height*0.5);
                // we cannot draw in the image !!! otherwise will mess with the prediction
                    // int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
                    // circle( img, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        p1 = center;
                        any_eye_detected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        two_eyes = true;
                    }
            }
        }

        std::cout << "SOME DEBUG" << endl;
        std::cout << "-------------------------" << endl;
        std::cout << "faces detected:" << (*faces).size() << endl;
        std::cout << "x: " << (*faces)[0].x << endl;
        std::cout << "y: " << (*faces)[0].y << endl;
        std::cout << "w: " << (*faces)[0].width << endl;
        std::cout << "h: " << (*faces)[0].height << endl << endl;
        Mat imageInRectangle;
        imageInRectangle = img((*faces)[0]);
        Size recFaceSize = imageInRectangle.size();
        std::cout << recFaceSize << endl;
        // for debug
        imwrite("C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\test_canny\\imageInRectangle.jpg", imageInRectangle);

        int rec_w = 0;
        int rec_h = (*faces)[0].height * 0.64;
        // checking the (x,y) for cropped rectangle
        // based in human anatomy
        int px = 0;
        int py = 2 * 0.125 * (*faces)[0].height;
        Mat cropImage;
        std::cout << "faces[0].x:" << (*faces)[0].x << endl;
        p1.x = p1.x - (*faces)[0].x;
        std::cout << "p1.x:" << p1.x << endl;

        if (any_eye_detected)
        {
            if (two_eyes)
            {
                std::cout << "two eyes detected" << endl;
                // we have detected two eyes
                // we have p1 and p2
                // left eye
                px = p1.x / 1.35;
            }
            else
            {
                // only one eye was found.. need to check if the
                // left or right eye
                // we have only p1
                if (p1.x > recFaceSize.width / 2)
                {
                    // right eye
                    std::cout << "only right eye detected" << endl;
                    px = p1.x / 1.75;
                }
                else
                {
                    // left eye
                    std::cout << "only left eye detected" << endl;
                    px = p1.x / 1.35;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            // no eyes detected but we have a face
            px = 25;
            py = 25;
            rec_w = recFaceSize.width - 50;
            rec_h = recFaceSize.height - 30;
        }
        rec_w = ((*faces)[0].width - px) * 0.75;
        std::cout << "px :" << px << endl;
        std::cout << "py :" << py << endl;
        std::cout << "rec_w:" << rec_w << endl;
        std::cout << "rec_h:" << rec_h << endl;

        cropImage = imageInRectangle(Rect(px, py, rec_w, rec_h));
        Size dstImgSize(70, 70); // same image size of db
        Mat finalSizeImg;
        resize(cropImage, finalSizeImg, dstImgSize);
        // for debug
        imwrite("C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\test_canny\\onlyface.jpg", finalSizeImg);

        cvtColor(finalSizeImg, finalSizeImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        return finalSizeImg;
}
```

I've debugged it and the error only pops up when I reach return 0 in the main method.

[And here's an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuobG.png)  (too large to embed)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a memory leak?

Comment: See if this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391892/change-opencv-image-format-to-matlab-format-debug-assertion-acrt-first-block or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310117/debug-assertion-failed-expression-acrt-first-block-header/35311928 apply